# Mongo using the wrong index during aggregation with match+sort operations

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB version `4.2.0`. I have a collection with the following indexes:

```js
{uuid: 1},
{unique: true, name: "uuid_idx"}
```

and

```js
{field1: 1, field2: 1, _id: 1},
{unique: true, name: "compound_idx"}
```

When executing this query

```js
aggregate([
  {"$match": {"uuid": <uuid_value>}}
])
```

the planner correctly selects `uuid_idx`.

When adding this sort clause

```js
aggregate([
  {"$match": {"uuid": <uuid_value>}},
  {"$sort": {"field1": 1, "field2": 1, "_id": 1}}
])
```

the planner selects `compound_idx`, which makes the query slower.

I would expect the sort clause to not make a difference in this context. **Why does Mongo not use the `uuid_idx` index in both cases**?

**EDIT**:
A little clarification, I understand there are workarounds to use the correct index, but I'm looking for an explanation of why this does not happen automatically (if possible with links to the official documentation). Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the query is dynamically generated and currently the sort clause is automatically inserted.

Comment: How many documents does the second aggregation query select (the one with match and sort stages)?

Answer (score 0):

**Why is this happening?:**

Lets understand how Mongo chooses which index to use as explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/query-plans/#query-optimization).

If a query can be satisfied by multiple indexes (satisfied is used losely as Mongo actually chooses all possibly relevant indexes) defined in the collection.

MongoDB will then test all the applicable indexes in parallel. The first index that can returns 101 results will be selected by the query planner.

Meaning that for that certain query that index actually wins.

**What can we do?:**

We can use [$hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor-hint), hint basically forces Mongo to use a specific index, however Mongo this is not recommended because if changes occur Mongo will not adapt to those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still confused. Your first link refers to version 2.6 and I cannot find the same explanation for version 4.2: is it still applicable? Also, from that link it looks like the selected index either *returns all matching results* or returns 101 results faster than all others. Could it be that `uuid_idx` is slower to return one match than `compound_idx` is to return 101 matches?

Comment: updated link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor-hint

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
aggregate( 
  [
    { $match : { uuid : "some_value" } },
    { $sort : { fld1: 1, fld2: 1, _id: 1 } }
  ],
)
```

doesn't use the index "uuid_idx".

There are couple of options you can work with for using indexes on both the *match* and *sort* operations:

*(1) Define a new compound index: { uuid: 1, fld1: 1, fld2: 1, _id: 1 }*

Both the *match* and *match+sort* queries will use this index (for both the match and sort operations).

*(2) Use the hint on the uuid index (using existing indexes)*

Both the *match* and *match+sort* queries will use this index (for both the match and sort operations).

```
aggregate( 
  [
    { $match : { uuid : "some_value" } },
    { $sort : { fld1: 1, fld2: 1, _id: 1 } }
  ],
  { hint: "uuid_idx"}
)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the planner always prioritizes the index on the sort clause, even if there is an index on the match clause with 100% selectivity? Is there any reference in the official documentation about this behavior?

Comment: No there is no such prioritization for _sort_ operations. In general, using two indexes on the same query is not the best practice; if a query can use one compound index for the match and sort  operations it is the best option.

Comment: The query optimizer generates multiple plans based on the available and viable indexes (aka candidate indexes). MongoDB uses an emperical (based on observation or experience) query optimizer. Each of the candidate plan is executed for a short period of time. The optimizer sees which plan performs the best during that period (the best is determined by various factors like fastest, more documents, or even one plan might complete during the trial, a threshold, etc.). Also, see [Query plans and caching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/).

Comment: I tried the following query, and found that it uses the `uuid_idx` (not the compound index as in the aggregation): `db.colln.find( {"uuid": <somevalue> } ).sort({ fld1: 1, fld2: 1, _id: 1 })`. And, the sort happens in the memory.

Comment: _But,_ when the compound index on four fields is applied on the _find.sort_ query, both the operations use the index.

Comment: Here is some more relevant info: [Index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) and [Sort and Non-prefix subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use find instead of aggregate, it will use the right index.  So this is still problem in aggregate pipeline.